# Three.js OrbitControls Pan 360

Tags: javascript, three.js, pan

I'm writing a program that solves the Rubiks Cube,
OrbitControls allow spinning infinitely and panning 180 only

can I tweak it to pan 360 as well?
I'm looking at these lines:

```
// How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
// Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

// How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
// If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
this.minAzimuthAngle = - Infinity; // radians
this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians
```

trying to get min and max Polar angle to work from -infinity to infinity.

I've also tried TrackballControls, but there the rotation is in all direction, while I only need UP/DOWN, RIGHT/LEFT. this makes it hard for the user to set the Cube strait.

here's a link to the project
http://www.five-software.com/rubiks/

Comment: Are you sure it is "panning" that you want? Panning the camera will make the camera look away from the cube.

Comment: @ Yariv Polar angle must be in [ 0, pi ]. You are using a revision of three.js that is 3 years old. I suggest you update to the current revision.

Comment: About the panning, I'm not sure I'm using the right term. When I enter the app, the cube appears with white side up, green to the left and red to the right. I can rotate the orbit(right/left), so that blue is on the left and orange is on the right. I'd like to be able to do the same up/down, so that yellow is on the top.

Comment: BTW, I was able to come with a workaround, changing the camera position and the view angle 
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
to
var VIEW_ANGLE = -45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
and
camera.position.set(-120, -120, -120);
to
camera.position.set(120, 120, 120);
I still think able to rotate 360 up/down is more natural